# How to pass TestNG groups comma separated(group1, group2) through terminal?

Tags: gradle, testng, gradlew

In my current build.gradle, i am using below target to run a specific group through command line

```
  test {
        jvmArgs "-DisParallel=true"
        useTestNG(){
            suites testngxml
            includeGroups System.properties['groups']
        }   
    }
```

Now i want to pass multiple groups with comma separated **gradlew clean test -Dgroups='group1,group2'**

any help please

Answer (score 1):

Why not manage this at the TestNG Suite xml file instead of trying to manage this at the Gradle build file level ?

You can make use of a BeanShell within your TestNG suite xml file, that has the ability to read the group name as a JVM argument and then parse it and run tests accordingly ?

Below is an example which accepts a group name as a JVM argument and then dynamically lets tests run if and only if they belong to the group name that was passed. You can enhance this by adding your split logic and then leveraging the same `containsKey()` logic.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
    <test name="Test">
        <method-selectors>
            <method-selector>
                <script language="beanshell">
                <![CDATA[whatGroup = System.getProperty("groups");
                groups.containsKey(whatGroup);
                ]]>
                </script>
            </method-selector>
        </method-selectors>
        <classes>
            <class name="organized.chaos.GroupsPlayGround" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

For more information you can refer to the following :

- [TestNG Documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#beanshell)
- [My Blog post](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/beanshell-and-testng/)

Comment: We store our data in DB and set the groups there. And we dynamically pass the group through command line(**gradlew test -Dgroups=group**)  . we are not using groups mentioned in test scripts/testng.xml

Comment: @nurav - The xml that I mention in my response doesn't have a groups section. It uses a beanshell method selector to dynamically decide the group to be included based upon what group you passed in via the JVM argument. So I dont quite understand what you mean by `use groups mentioned in test scripts/testng.xml`. Btw.. what issue are you facing when you pass in multiple groups via the JVM arguments in your current gradle setup. Care to elaborate ?